# Stream YAML output, rather than loading everything into memory

Tags: perl, stream, yaml, xs

I am using Perl with `YAML::XS` to write YAML output. Specifically, this YAML output is a list of the contents of other YAML files. I'm doing so, for example, like this:

```perl
use YAML::XS qw(LoadFile DumpFile);

my @yaml_files = qw(foo.yaml bar.yaml quux.yaml);

DumpFile("output.yaml", [
   map { LoadFile($_) } @yaml_files
]);
```

My understanding is that this will load every input YAML file into memory to create the list, then finally write the output to disk. In general, that makes sense, but in this case, there's an opportunity to stream the output one list item at a time. How can this be done, if it's indeed possible, with `YAML::XS`?

---

Notes:

- I *could* do some string manipulation myself, to stream the list output -- rather than using `DumpFile` -- but that relies on me outputting correct YAML. It's relatively trivial in this case, but I'd rather defer to library code.
- My environment is pretty constrained. I have `YAML::XS`, but that's it beyond the standard library.

Comment: No _______________

Comment: `YAML::XS` does bundle a fully-featured libyaml, which has this capability. However those parts are not exposed. I don't know enough Perl to know whether you could access them somehow (e.g. via manually linking to the C symbols).